# Particles of a particle system react not as an own object

Tags: system

I have an ATM and would like the money to fly out from it. 
I have made the cash box into a particle system.

The money flies out of the cash box, but it flies downwards, because the bill also flies downwards.

Is it possible to make the money (particle) independent from the banknote ?

[[image]
[[image]
[[image]

Comment: Are you saying you have bills as well as coins, and want them to behave differently? You can add 2 different particle systems to the same object, and have them behave independently, if that helps.

Comment: No sry, i have just bills and and under the render as tab i choosed the modeled bill. 
So all bills (the particles) which are flying out of the Atm are behaving like the one i modeled

Comment: Ok, and what are you hoping will happen? What do you mean by making the money independent from the Banknote? Do you mean you used the note as a particle instance, but still want to have a note object as well?

Comment: Exactly, I don't want the bills coming out of the machine to depend on the note as a particle instance

Comment: Couldn't you just duplicate the object (shift-d), and remove the particle system from the duplicate?

Comment: mhh what are u mean? 
The problem is I added forces. I want these forces and gravity to affect the particles. But they affect the banknote that transmits the motion to the particles. But I don't want that.

Comment: Oh, ok. Nevermind,.. I'm not sure I know how to solve that. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove gravity from the emission simulation:

[image]

Comment: but then the particles has no gravats

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I get the impression you want your bills to fly a bit as if they moved along a curve. Like an airplane diving and not like it was dropping out of the sky as a brick.

If this is what you're looking for, you can do the following: Select the object that is emitting your particles. Then in the Properties window go to the Particle Properties tab, check the box Rotation, and under Rotation check the box Dynamic. (Personally i got the best result if I also choose "Velocity / Hair" as the Orientation Axis.)

[image]

Also if the direction the particles are flying is not to your liking, you can make your particles follow a curve object, like a bezier curve.

First simply place the start of the curve near the particle emitter object. With the curve selected go to the Physics Properties tab in the Properties window. Then click on Force Field, and under Force Fields change the Type to Curve Guide. The particle spawned at the start of the curve will now automatically follow the path of the curve.

[image]

I hope that helps.